# FlurryAnalytics simple installation not registering any app activity

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I have included Flurry according the instructions I received on registering. I get no errors when I build my app and have successfully submitted to the AppStore including Flurry but it is clearly not working because I am not seeing any activity recorded in the dashboard.
I have the following code in my app delegate:

```
#import "FlurryAnalytics.h"
```

and (with some changes in the actual API ID)

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
[FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"XXXX66V713R52CYTV9G"];
}
```

And in XCODE I have a yellow FlurryAnalitics folder which can be seen in the screen grab which I have attached. 
[image]
Please could you tell me what I am doing wrong because I have been over the instructions so many times and cannot see what I have missed.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: This is probably should be a technical support request toward Flurry Analytics...

Comment: Also, you obfuscated the first part of your session ID in your posted code but failed to do so at the bottom of your screenshot. Whoops. You might want to change your session ID.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I have logged a support ticket with Flurry but I have not yet had any response. Also the instructions dont quite match the current version of XCODE. Everyone on SO has been really helpful in the past so I thought I would post the question to see if there was an obvious answer. Again many thanks for your response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first place the flurry initialization code in your applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and delete your applicationDidFinishLaunching function. You do not need your app to be submitted to the store to test out flurry and you should be able to see activity from your testing. Have your put a breakpoint at your initialization code? If it is being hit correctly then try contacting flurry or setting up another app on their system. There can sometimes be a long lag between recorded events and them showing up on Flurry's dashboard.

Comment: Glad to hear it. One more recommendation is to implement flurry's crash log reporter if you haven't already because that can be more valuable than the other reporting. There is a 2 step instruction that flurry gives you in the SDK download page.